# Is there a test/model to tell whether an individual deviates from a group?

Tags: regression, time-series, group-differences, anomaly-detection, dynamic-regression

I'm working with time-series data on a handful (about 12) of individuals. Under normal conditions, the  variable of interest for each individual is correlated among the group, i.e. if `y` is high for one individual, it's high for all individuals and vice versa (However, not necessarily 1:1). There are other variables `x=(x_1,...,x_n)` that can influence `y` for each individual differently and therefore explain some of the deviation from the group.

**The problem:** I want to test whether one individual at some point in time deviates from the group *for a prolonged period of time*, where the deviation *cannot* be explained by `x`. I am essentially looking for a point in time where the value of `y` for one individual can no longer be explained by the group. Is there a type of test or model that can achieve this?

Comment: maybe add the tag [tag:anomaly-detection]?

Comment: Is this "one individual" specified as part of the test, or do you mean whether *there exist* one (or more) individuals that depart from the group?

Comment: @whuber In this particular case, I know who the individual is, but the ideal model would also point out who the individual(s) is (are).

Comment: Those are rather different problems: it's much harder to tell *whether* there is such an individual and to identify them than it is to compare one individual to all the others.  Although the approaches would naturally be related, the solutions can differ quite a bit.  The source of the difficulty is that when you suspect an individual, you don't have to use their data to characterize the group tendency; but when you don't know who the outliers are, such a straightforward approach is no longer possible.

Comment: @whuber Exactly. But I can't believe that there isn't any research related to this. It seems like a rather relevant problem. However, if you know of any research on anomaly detection within a group where the deviant is known, that would also be really helpful.

Comment: There are natural ways to resolve this.  You appear to describe a problem in which you wish to characterize a group of *residuals* in a model over time.  That's a *multivariate changepoint* problem.  There exist some very good recent solutions, such as [ECP](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ecp/index.html). The literature on changepoint problems is large and there exist a great many variations on those problems, which is why it would be helpful to pin down the nature of your data and the specific question you have as narrowly as possible.

Comment: @whuber Thank you! That is already a huge help

Comment: @whuber I am working with daily data on the number of goods in stock for 12-60 companies. Under normal conditions, these numbers are determined by several variables, some of which are hidden or the exact relationship is too complex to model. However, we would expect that all companies choose their number of goods in stock to maximize profits, which leads to high correlation between different individuals. I suspect that at some point a particular company stopped maximizing profits and therefore its behavior could no longer be predicted by the group (and other control variables).